# Jquery loop after click

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach

I'm using Jquery to submit a form. I want to loop through the form after the user clicks on a submit button to get the select option. There are many different select fields. The select options are generated using PHP.

**A sample of the HTML:**

```
<select id="selectHome_1">
 <option></option>
</select>

<select id="selectHome_2">
  <option></option>
</select>

<inpupt type="submit" id="update" />
```

**The JQuery**

```
$("#update").click(function() {        
   //Loop through all select fields
   $("input[id^='selectHome_']").each(function(){
  //Production code will do other things        
     alert('test');//Test to see if it works...
   });
});
```

The code that searches for *id=selectHome_* is not working (the alert box never shows).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot your `:` infront of `input`:

```
$(":input[id^='selectHome_']").each();
```

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$("select[id^='selectHome_']")
```

and test with

```
alert($("select[id^='selectHome_']").length)
```

Comment: +1 Excellent. Much better now :) Thank you for handling correction in such a good way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on testing by checking the length.